# How to convert a string to a multi-level JSON?

Tags: python, html, json

I have an HTML file structured this way:

> Section 1.1
> 1.1.1 random paragraph
> 1.1.1.1 random paragraph
>
> Section 1.2
> 1.2.1 random paragraph
> 1.2.1.1 random paragraph
> ...
>
> Section 11.4 ...
> 11.4.12 random paragraph
> 11.2.12.1 random paragraph

HTML example:

```
<p>
  <span class="c1"
    >Section 1.1.<span class="c7">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>Organization and
    Application</span
  >
</p>
<p>
  <span class="c1"
    >1.1.1.<span class="c7">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>Organization of this Code</span
  >
</p>
<p align="justify">
  <span class="c1">1.1.1.1.&nbsp;&nbsp;Scope of Division A</span>
</p>
<p align="justify">
  <span
    ><b>(1)&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>Division A contains compliance and application
    provisions and the <i>objectives</i> and <i>functional statements</i> of
    this Code.</span
  >
</p>
<p align="justify">
  <span class="c1">1.1.1.2.&nbsp;&nbsp;Scope of Division B</span>
</p>
<p align="justify">
  <span
    ><b>(1)&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>Division B contains the
    <i>acceptable solutions</i> of this Code.</span
  >
</p>
<p align="justify">
  <span class="c1">1.1.1.3.&nbsp;&nbsp;Scope of Division C</span>
</p>
```

I have figured out the regEx to find each Section, SubSection, and so on.

```
sect1 = re.compile(r"class=\"c1\">(Section )?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[^0-9]")
sect2 = re.compile(r"class=\"c1\">[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[^0-9]")
sect3 = re.compile(r"class=\"c1\">[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[^0-9]")
sect4 = re.compile(r"class=\"c1\">[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[^0-9]")
```

I can create a first-level "key-value" pair list for the Sections and the HTML contained in them:

`def stringToList(string, devider):` takes in a string and a regEx ;returns `list [[ name, resultHtml],[ name, resultHtml]]`

```
def stringToList(string, devider):
    matches = re.finditer(devider, string)

    matchArr= []
    for   m in matches :
  
        try:
            lastMatch
        except NameError:
            x=True
        else: 
            start = lastMatch.start()
            end = m.start()    
            resultHtml = page[start:end] # html string starting with last match, ending with current match
            name = lastMatch.group().replace('class="c1">','').replace('<','') # match group from last match minus the regEx Tags 
            matchArr.append([ name, resultHtml])

        lastMatch= m 
    return matchArr   #returns list[[ name, resultHtml],[ name, resultHtml]]
```

This returns a list of section names and the HTML associated with those sections.
How do I further sort the list to create a structure like:

```
main: {
    {
        1: {
            {
                1.1: {
                      1.1.1:html,
                      1.1.2:html,
                      }
            },
        
        
        }
```

The final goal is to have a list of nested links to each html.
Is this the best approach to reach the goal? Any input or advice is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML doesn't have a proper format, but it's still possible to achieve the result your after. It does require a bit more work:

```py
html = """
<p>
    <span class="c1">Section 1.1.<span class="c7">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>Organization and
        Application</span>
</p>
<p>
    <span class="c1">1.1.1.<span class="c7">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>Organization of this Code</span>
</p>
<p align="justify">
    <span class="c1">1.1.1.1.&nbsp;&nbsp;Scope of Division A</span>
</p>
<p align="justify">
    <span><b>(1)&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>Division A contains compliance and application
        provisions and the <i>objectives</i> and <i>functional statements</i> of
        this Code.</span>
</p>
<p align="justify">
    <span class="c1">1.1.1.2.&nbsp;&nbsp;Scope of Division B</span>
</p>
<p align="justify">
    <span><b>(1)&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>Division B contains the
        <i>acceptable solutions</i> of this Code.</span>
</p>
<p align="justify">
    <span class="c1">1.1.1.3.&nbsp;&nbsp;Scope of Division C</span>
</p>
"""

import re
import json

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Parse the HTML so we can search it
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

# Create a placeholder for the output
output = {}

# Keep track of how deep we are nested
last_section_number = "1"


def clean_text(text: str) -> str:
    """ Helper method to clean texts.

    Args:
        text (str): The input text

    Returns:
        str: The clean output
    """
    text = text.replace("\u00a0", " ")
    text = " ".join([line.strip() for line in text.split("\n")])
    return text


# Every part of the document seems to start with a <p> tag
for part in soup.find_all("p"):

    # If the part is a section title (or subsection title) it has a span with class="c1"
    section_title = part.find("span", "c1")
    if section_title is not None:

        # Extract the section number with regex
        section_number = re.search(r"(\d+\.)+", section_title.text).group(0).strip(".")

        def _set_nested(section_number: str, subsection: dict) -> dict:
            """ Method to traverse down into a dictionary based on
            a section number, formatted as a string.

            Args:
                section_number (str): The section number to traverse to (e.g. "1.1")
                subsection (dict): The subsection of the current section

            Returns:
                dict: The updated section
            """

            # Split the section number, keep the first part as the main
            main, *rest = section_number.split(".")

            # If there is no "rest" there are no deeper levels
            if len(rest) <= 0:
                subsection[main] = {
                    "title": clean_text(section_title.text),
                }
                return subsection

            # Recombine the "rest" into a new section number
            rest = ".".join(rest)

            # Use the "rest" to traverse down into the output dictionary
            subsection[main] = _set_nested(rest, subsection.get(main, {}))

            # Return the final output
            return subsection

        # Use the section number to set a part of a dictionary
        output = _set_nested(section_number=section_number, subsection=output)

        # Store the last section number processed
        last_section_number = section_number

    # If this part has no title, it's a piece of content
    else:

        def _set_nested(section_number: str, subsection: dict) -> dict:

            # Split the section number, keep the first part as the main
            main, *rest = section_number.split(".")

            # If there is no "rest" there are no deeper levels
            if len(rest) <= 0:
                subsection[main]["content"] = clean_text(part.text)
                return subsection

            # Recombine the "rest" into a new section number
            rest = ".".join(rest)

            # Use the "rest" to traverse down into the output dictionary
            subsection[main] = _set_nested(rest, subsection[main])

            # Return the final output
            return subsection

        # Use the last section number to set a part of a dictionary
        output = _set_nested(last_section_number, output)


print(json.dumps(output, indent=2))
```

Output:

```py
{
  "1": {
    "1": {
      "title": "Section 1.1.  Organization and Application",
      "1": {
        "title": "1.1.1.  Organization of this Code",
        "1": {
          "title": "1.1.1.1.  Scope of Division A",
          "content": " (1)  Division A contains compliance and application provisions and the objectives and functional statements of this Code. "
        },
        "2": {
          "title": "1.1.1.2.  Scope of Division B",
          "content": " (1)  Division B contains the acceptable solutions of this Code. "
        },
        "3": {
          "title": "1.1.1.3.  Scope of Division C"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Previous answer:

> Don't use regex, use BeautifulSoup (https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)!
>
> ```py
> soup = BeautifulSoup("<YOUR HTML AS STRING>")
>
> for section in soup.find_all("h1", "c1"):
>     ... nested here ...
> ```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out. Can I use lxml BeautifulSoup Parser to achieve the same result?

Comment: Sure, why not? You didn't provide an example of your HTML, so it's a little hard to judge, but should work just fine.

Comment: I added an HTML snippet

Comment: I've updated my answer, it now works on the snippet you provided.